# Playstation Network Login Issues

Tags: ps4, psn

when I first got a ps4 I immediately created a psn account and bought a couple of games on the store itself. Mortal Kombat XL, GTA V, Assassin's Creed IV, and Ratchet & Clank. These games are quite sizable and because my internet isn't too fast they took quite long to download, so the PSN store was definitely working fine for a couple of weeks (4-5 weeks at most). Then I started noticing a problem logging in at my house with these two screenshots.

I tried everything and nothing worked. Then when I was at my sisters house, I was able to access store.playstation.com through her internet connection. So I assumed psn was down for maintenance but when I got back home it wasn't still wasn't working on mine. I assumed my IP was banned for some reason but then when I tried to log into my account at my sister's house a few weeks after it was also now not working. After a few weeks on not being able to access psn I tried again just out of curiosity and to my surprise it worked. But only for a few days. It has been doing this for the past few months, not access for long periods and then access for like a few days and then it's down again.

Can someone please help? I'm here because Sony said it's my fault when I know I didn't do anything malicious.

[image: When I try login to playstation.com]

[image: When I try access the store.playstation.com url]

Comment: Where does Sony say it's your fault?

Comment: Can you provide context about the 2 images you posted? from my understanding the only way you would have gotten them is if you accessed those pages via a browser and the PS4 has it's own PlaystationStore App which you would use for downloading games which to my knowledge wont show those if PSN was offline or if there was problem with your connection

Comment: also if Sony is saying it's your fault they probably mean that the problem is on you end with your connection, not theirs since you seem to have no trouble when you connect in another location

Comment: The first image is when I try and sign into the playstation website and the second one is when I try to go to 'store.playstation.com'. Sony says it might be a problem with my ISP but it's not a consistent problem as I am sometimes able to log into both playstation.com and store.playstation.com for a few days at a time then the cycles starts again.